# Create Columns Percentage of Total Based on Referenced Strings In List Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that is essentially some indexes with a pivot table of columns with values in the rows of 1's and 0's. One column 'Total' is the total of the 1's across a given row. Each column name is the first index of items in a list that I referenced. What I would like to do is create columns for percent of the total column referencing these columns and pulling the third index which is a string which represents a region in the world such as 'United States', 'Germany', etc.

Dataframe below:

```
Name     Total  Option1  Option2  Option3  Option4  Option5  Option6  Option7
Michael   4       1        0        0        1        0        1        1
Gerry     2       1        0        0        0        0        0        1
```

List that is referenced for pivot table dataframe

```
ids = [('Option1', '37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd', 'United States'), 
('Option2', '37i9dQZF1DX2RxBh64BHjQ', 'Germany'), 
('Option3', '37i9dQZF1DX5hR0J49CmXC', 'Denmark'), 
('Option4', '37i9dQZF1DX8f6LHxMjnzD', 'Australia'), 
('Option5', '37i9dQZF1DWSOkubnsDCSS', 'United Kingdom'), 
('Option6', '37i9dQZF1DX0QKpU3cGsyb', 'United States'), 
('Option7', '37i9dQZF1DX60OAKjsWlA2', 'United States')]
```

Expected Output

```
Name     Total  %United States  %Germany   %Denmark   %Australia  %United Kingdom  Option1  Option2  Option3  Option4  Option5  Option6  Option7
Michael   4         .75             0          0          .25            0            1        0        0        1        0        1        1
Gerry     2          1              0          0           0             0            1        0        0        0        0        0        1
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. You haven't even provided a decent [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can map the columns and groupby:

```
# assuming that Name are unique
df = df.set_index('Name')

renamed = df.columns[1:].map(pd.DataFrame(ids).set_index(0)[2])

(df.iloc[:,1:].T
   .groupby(renamed).sum().T
   .div(df['Total'], axis=0)
   .assign(Total=df['Total'])
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
      Name  Australia  Denmark  Germany  United Kingdom  United States  Total
0  Michael       0.25      0.0      0.0             0.0           0.75      4
1    Gerry       0.00      0.0      0.0             0.0           1.00      2
```